# Dell PowerEdge T130 with S130 RAID Controller - Driver for Windows Server 2016 nonexistent

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc, windows-server-2016

So I have Dell PowerEdge T130 tower server, and I wish to install Windows Server 2016 Essentials on it.

When I configure RAID in Dell Lifecycle Controller everything is fine, but when I try to run installation it asks me for drivers.

I've looked few hours for them, used older from WS 2008 and 2012 and it doesn't accept it.

This page says that the server supports Windows Server 2016:
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/SupportedOS/poweredge-t130

This page (S130 RAID Controller manual) says it supports only 2012, 2012 R2 and 2008.
http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/poweredge-rc-s130/sw130_ug_pub-v1/Supported-operating-systems?guid=GUID-EC917530-4994-4339-AF17-F1B7B8C9097A&lang=en-us

Can anyone help me finding proper drivers or find a solution to make PowerEdge T130, Windows Server 2016 with RAID configured work?

If I won't configure RAID controller and use regular SATA one everything is fine.

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: So the server supports Windows Server 2016 but the RAID controller doesn't. Either install an OS that is supported by the RAID controller or get a RAID controller that supports Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I'm afraid it's integrated. If the controller is installed in PowerEdge T130 and it doesn't support Windows Server 2016, this OS shouldn't be in a list of supported OS's for PowerEdge T130 Tower Server.

Comment: I have three possible solutions. Will try each of them, if anything works I'll post an answer here.

Comment: Have you tried this S130 driver which is made for W2016 ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and finaly found these. I finaly found the correct version of the drivers were listed as being for Server v-Next (2016) 
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=NPMVJ

Answer (score 0):

You own branded server, all the point of paying its price is support included into it. Why you are not using it?

According to Dell's official document "[Dell - Microsoft OS Support Matrix](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20438149/download.aspx)" PowerEdge T130 qualified for Windows Server 2016 suppot (Essentials & Standard edition). As per the same document **qualified** means that:

"*Dell™ Engineering has successfully tested and validated the current and immediately preceding released operating system (OS) version on Dell PowerEdge™ Servers. Dell adheres to all published partner test plans to ensure OS compatibility and provides full technical support for the Dell hardware components running on the OS. Dell Qualified systems have OpenManage support.*"

So for you it just be as simple as contacting Dell support (and maybe share the solution with us if you want). Otherwise, why buying branded hardware and fiddling with it like with some custom-built box with no support?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. You have to insert the installation media, go in the lifecycle controller, setup your RAID and then launch the OS installation from there. (Choose Windows Server 2016)

It seems to load driver into the system so they are available next time you try your installation.